# Getting value of multi array in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

How can I get the values of `id` in this array within a for loop?

```
var image_array = [
    {image: 'images/candidates/1.jpg', link_url: 'images/candidates/1.jpg', link_rel: 'prettyPhoto', id: 0 }, 
        // image for the first layer, goes with the text from id="sw0"
    {image: 'images/candidates/2.jpg', link_url: 'images/candidates/2.jpg', link_rel: 'prettyPhoto', id: 1 },
        // image for the second layer, goes with the text from id="sw1"
    {image: 'images/candidates/3.jpg', link_url: 'images/candidates/3.jpg', link_rel: 'prettyPhoto', id: 2 },
        // image for the third layer, goes with the text from id="sw2"
    {image: 'images/candidates/4.jpg', link_url: 'images/candidates/4.jpg', link_rel: 'prettyPhoto', id: 3},
        // image for the fourth layer, goes with the text from id="sw3"
    {image: 'images/candidates/5.jpg', link_url: 'images/candidates/5.jpg', link_rel: 'prettyPhoto', id: 4},
        // image for the fifth layer, goes with the text from id="sw4"
    {image: 'images/candidates/6.jpg', link_url: 'images/candidates/6.jpg', link_rel: 'prettyPhoto', id: 5},
        // image for the sixth layer, goes with the text from id="sw5"
    {image: 'images/candidates/7.jpg', link_url: 'images/candidates/7.jpg', link_rel: 'prettyPhoto', id: 6},
        // image for the seventh layer, goes with the text from id="sw6"
    {image: 'images/candidates/8.jpg', link_url: 'images/candidates/8.jpg', link_rel: 'prettyPhoto', id: 7},
        // image for the eighth layer, goes with the text from id="sw7"
    {image: 'images/candidates/9.jpg', link_url: 'images/candidates/9.jpg', link_rel: 'prettyPhoto', id: 8},
        // image for the ninth layer, goes with the text from id="sw8"
    {image: 'images/candidates/10.jpg', link_url: 'images/candidates/10.jpg', link_rel: 'prettyPhoto', id: 9},
        // image for the tenth layer, goes with the text from id="sw9"
    {image: 'images/candidates/11.jpg', link_url: 'images/candidates/11.jpg', link_rel: 'prettyPhoto', id: 10}
        // image for the eleventh layer, goes with the text from id="sw10"
];
```

Also, would be great if I could retrieve it as an integer, as the way it is being stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
for (i = 0; i<image_array.length;i++){
    console.log(image_array[i].id);
}
```

If you want one specific you can use for example `image_array[2].id` which gives you `2`

### Demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/9cNrU/)

(look at console)

Comment: It seems that you are the only 1 that actually answered my question.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you've got jquery to work with, this beauty will give you an array of the ids.

```
var image_array_by_id = $.map(image_array, function (index) { return index.id });
```