# Get values of array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

For some reason I am having the hardest time get to values of an object stored within an array.
Here is how I am populating my array:

```
var arrActivities = []; 

//other not needed variables here.. 

function logIt(){
firebase.firestore().collection('PostedFunActivities').where("geolocation", ">=", range.lower).where("geolocation", "<=", range.upper).get().then((querySnapshot) =>{
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) =>{ 
            arrActivities.push(doc.data());                                         
    })
});
       console.log(arrActivities);
       console.log(arrActivities.length);
}
```

The result of my `console.log` is the following:

```
[]
    0: {location: "Mānana Ridge Trail, Pearl City, HI, USA", geolocation: "87z9yj0x5"}
    1: {timePosted: "13:50:05 GMT-1000 (HST)", geolocation: "87zc52x78"}
    2: {userId: "QevGxIV57lZuC92oTjp80N9WcIy2", title: "Koko crater arch"}
    3: {timePosted: "13:46:55 GMT-1000 (HST)", image: "0.1565895502212029"}
    4: {title: "Bike", datePosted: "Fri Jun 12 2020"}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I feel like i tried a million way to get either the length of the array or the values within, but I cannot get to any of that.
Some of my attempts involve suggestions coming from these SO posts (these attempts are to get the lenght):
[data.length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282989/getting-value-of-multi-array-in-js) 
[Object.keys(data).length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-a-javascript-object)

I would really appreciate any suggestions on how to get the length and values of my objects.

***My Objective** 
I need to get the length of the array which in this case would be 5. Also I need to be able to get into my values for example the the `userId` within the 3rd element in the array.

Comment: `arr.reduce((sum,x)=>Object.keys(x).length+sum,0)`?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @user120242 I added my objective to the post, I tried your solution, but I when I log it I still get a 0.

Comment: Are you using firebase?  `querySnapshot.size`

Comment: I am using Firebase, let me add that.

Comment: Did you make sure to await or use a callback to make sure the query results are ready before you try to propagate it?  It looks to me like your array was initially empty, and the data was propagated after you console.log'd it, so your code is actually receiving the empty array before the query results were added to it

Comment: @user120242 mmm.. I do see what you are saying.. where would you add the await? in that statement I do not have anything that returns..

Comment: It's already in a Promise callback, so it should be ready by then.  Did you check the snapshot's `.size`?  Or check `.empty`?  If it's empty, maybe you filled the array with data later somewhere else?  Note, if you are trying to access arrActivities anywhere else, if it runs before the Promise resolves and fills it with data, you will get an empty arrActivites.  Also, are you sure arrActivities is within the scope you are trying to access it from?

Comment: True.. `.size` returns 5 and `.empty` is false. I am pretty sure everything is within the scope. Also, the only place where I am manipulating arrActivities is in that firebase promise statement.

Comment: If you call `logIt` multiple times, there may be times when it's empty; but console.log may still show data when you look at it, because it is showing it by reference (and by the time you go to look it has been filled in).  If you have code that tries to access (read) arrActivities outside of that promise, it may be empty on access.   If it's snot this, there's probably more information needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @Lennholm Not entirely as I am getting the content that I need from my requests. I can see it in my `console.log()`, but I cannot access it to save my life..

Comment: @user120242 Quite interesting because I call logIt on button click so it would get callled only as much as I click on the button..

Comment: @IlllIl your console.log is outside your Promise then callback.  arrActivities has not been populated when you called console.log

Comment: @user120242 You were right, thanks for all the help man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your code is asynchronous:

```
function logIt(){
    firebase.firestore().collection('PostedFunActivities').where("geolocation", ">=", range.lower).where("geolocation", "<=", range.upper).get().then((querySnapshot) =>{
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) =>{ 
                arrActivities.push(doc.data());                                         
        })
   });
   
   console.log(arrActivities);
   console.log(arrActivities.length);
}
```

The `.then` means that your anonymous arrow function callback will only populate the `arrActivities` array when the `.get()` promise resolves.

The reason the `console.log` was showing a filled array with length but the `arrActivites.length` wasn't is because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42991854/console-logarray-returns-filled-array-but-console-logarray-length-is-0/42991914). Namely, `console.log` shows the array as it is ("live"), whereas `.length` accesses the `length` property of the array when the statement is executed.

Essentially `console.log`ing a variable may asynchronously show that variable as a live reference, so by the time you see the logged output it may be changed from when it was first logged. On the other hand, accessing the `length` property of the array is guaranteed to be synchronous, meaning that when you log the length of the array, the value logged is unchanging.

One solution for this would be to wrap your `logIt` function body in a Promise, and then simply wait for the returned `arrActivities`:

```
function logIt(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        firebase.firestore().collection('PostedFunActivities').where("geolocation", ">=", range.lower).where("geolocation", "<=", range.upper).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) =>{ 
                arrActivities.push(doc.data());                                         
            })
            resolve(arrActivities);
        });
    });
}


logIt().then((result) => {
    console.log(result.length);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the length of each item in the array:

```
for (const item of arrActivities) {
    console.log(Object.keys(item).length);
}
```

To store the lengths of the items in the array in another array:

```
let arrLength = [];
for (const item of arrActivities) {
    arrLength.push(Object.keys(item).length);
}
```

To get the length of the array:

```
console.log(arrActivities.length);
```

To get the number of items in all objects of the array, i.e. the total number of object values of the items in the array:

```
let total = 0;
for (const item of arrActivities) {
    total += Object.keys(item).length;
}
console.log(total);
```

Comment: I am not necessarily trying to get the length of each object in the array.I am simply trying to get the length of the array.

Comment: This should be trivial, not sure if I am missing something. In any case, please see edit.

Comment: It really should be very trivial, but for some odd reason I cannot figure it out.. When I `console.log(arrActivities.length);` I get an `undefined`. I starting to think that the way the array is built with the `arrActivities.push(doc.data())` is messing things up.

Comment: Can you post more context? Specifically where you are trying to access the array length, and where the array is declared.

Comment: I added some more context. it's a pretty trivial operation, but somehow I am missing something..

Comment: arrActivities.length being undefined means that it is not an array or array-like.

Comment: @user120242 What would it be then? From what the log tells me it appears to me to be a very common array of objects.

Comment: use `console.log(JSON.stringify(arrActivities))`.  Or add a breakpoint in the debugger and check what the local variable values are.

Comment: Is there any asynchronous code acting in the `arrActivities` variable?

Comment: @zr0gravity7 check the main comments on OP for more info: According to OP that segment of code only executes on a button click he controls, and the only place arrActivities is manipulated on is inside the Promise callback